# Native event not triggered and its occur scipt error

Tags: blazor

```
@code {

public static RenderFragment xxx = @<button @onclick="Clicked">Click</button>;

public void Clicked()
{

}
```

}

Blazor App: error CS0026: Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer

I have removed static keyword, does not Build sample.

```
public RenderFragment xxx = @<button @onclick="Clicked">Click</button>;

public void Clicked()
{
}
```

Its occur below  error
error CS0027: Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context

Comment: Maybe remove `static` ?

Comment: i have removed the static keyword, does not build